# Dissecting gerund phrase

Tags: gerunds

The first sentence on this page, https://www.wired.com/2015/02/powerspy-phone-tracking/, says:

> SMARTPHONE USERS MIGHT balk at letting a random app like Candy Crush or Shazam track their every move via GPS.

Now I have confusion:

1. Is "letting a random app like Candy Crush or Shazam track their every move via GPS" a gerund phrase? If so, what are "letting" and "track" called in this case? Is "letting track" considered as one verb?
2. Is "random app like Candy Crush or Shazam" called the "subject" in this case? If so, is it right for a sentence to have two subjects like "SMARTPHONE USERS" and "random app like Candy Crush or Shazam"? Or there is a different term for "random app like Candy Crush or Shazam"?

Comment: Can you tell us why you think _let_ and _track_ should be considered as one verb? _Let_ often takes another verb's infinitive. Here is takes the infinitive _track._ Have you studied the English verb [_**let?**_](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/let_1)

Comment: Hi @P.E.Dant, I was just thinking how the verb `track` agrees with the rest of the sentence, so I thought `let track` or `letting track` is a verb phrase. No, I did not study advance usages of the verb `let`.

I am having problems dissecting and identifying the parts of the given sentence, it seems too advance for me.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, the other reason I'm thinking `let` and `track` is one verb is that based on what I learned so far, adding `to` before the word `track` is wrong in the given sentence. So, I thought that an additional explanation why adding `to` before the word `track` in the given sentence is wrong is because `let track` or `letting track` is one verb. That's how my mind works.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, for example, I asked about `to` in this question, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/357981/usage-of-to-in-the-mentioned-sentence, and according to those who commented and answered so far, using `to` in the sentence is wrong because `to` is only used for objects and not subjects. So that has led me to ask the second question here (above). Also, the reason `to` is wrong is still not very clear to me, so I asked myself, is it because `let track` or `letting track` is one verb that's why there should be no `to` before the word `track`?

Comment: There is nothing advanced about this usage of the verb _let._ This is the most common of its uses. For example, in _"Let me go"_, _let_ takes the infinitive _(to) go._ It might be better to learn about this very basic verb before moving to complicated sentences. [**Here**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/let_1) is a good place to start.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, you mentioned `Let often takes another verb's infinitive. Here is takes the infinitive <i>track</i>`, may I know your comment if I add `to` to the sentence like `SMARTPHONE USERS MIGHT balk at letting a random app like Candy Crush or Shazam to track their every move via GPS`? So now, it is using the `to` infinitive.

Comment: "Let" takes the unmarked infinitive. I strongly recommend that you study and understand this very basic English verb before trying to move to more complicated sentences

Comment: Thanks @P.E.Dant, I will check it out and ask here if I encounter something confusing.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, I have read about `let` and found out that it doesn't have a passive voice so using `to` is not even possible with it (based on what I've read). So I think I now understand how `track` agrees with `let` and vice versa. So my question now is, is `letting a random app like Candy Crush or Shazam track their every move via GPS` called a gerund phrase in the sentence I posted? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is a gerund phrase.